# Adding custom attributes to ejs template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I am using ejs template engine in my nodejs project, I have outputted text element by below code

`<%- text_field_tag('empId', '', {id: 'empId', Class: 'some_class', type: 'text'}) %>`

Now for using AngularJs advantages I want to add ng-model attribute, So I have modified code as below

`<%- text_field_tag('empId', '', {id: 'empId', Class: 'some_class', type: 'text', ng-model: "empId"}) %>`

But this ends with error -- As below

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/views/add.ejs while compiling ejs`

Let me know how should I achieve this?

Comment: @AntoineEsteve answer is correct. Use `'ng-model': 'empId'`.

Comment: I think AntoineEsteve has removed his answer and that was not working

Comment: Looking at your comment to @AntoineEsteve you use `'ng-model'='empId'` instead of `'ng-model':'empId'`.

Comment: Yes its working -- My mistake I have used = instead of :  Thanks Aleksandr. Can we have that answer ?

Comment: Wait for Antoine to un-delete his answer, and if not then you can self answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-model need to be in single quot

`<%- text_field_tag('empId', '', {id: 'empId', Class: 'some_class', type: 'text', 'ng-model': "empId"}) %>`

This works